# What is the correct approach to use filter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `filter()` and I am wondering is this correct approach?

Using filter, It look for matching `noteid` and remove the image.

```
$.post("monitoring_ajax.php", {
    action: "removeNote",
    noteid: noteid
}, function(data) {

    $(".noteicon").filter(function(){  
        if ($(this).data('note-id') == noteid) {
            $('img', this).remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: In your case, use `.each()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> [**`.filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):
>
> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Therefore I'd suggest using the `.filter()` method to **reduce** the selected elements, and *then* chain additional methods on the matched elements.

In your case, you could use:

```
$(".noteicon").filter(function(){  
    return $(this).data('note-id') == noteid; // Returns element if true
}).find('img').remove();
```

If you don't modify your code, then `.each()` may be a better substitute for `.filter()` since you a merely iterating over the code:

```
$(".noteicon").each(function(){  
    if ($(this).data('note-id') == noteid) {
        $('img', this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is `.each()` may be a better substitute for `.filter()` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Because filter *should* be a pure function, only reducing the set of selected elements. On the other hand `each` is only useful for side-effects, such as actually removing the element(s). So it's best to do filter-and-then-remove or each-with-remove; but not filter-with-remove.